# Char to Int, change int value, back to char, and add to a string

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I feel that I am extremely close to solving this issue. Provided a string, I want to convert the char from the string to an int, add a value from another method (`getKey`) to this number, and if the result is greater than 26, subtract 26. Then, convert this new `int` to its `char`, and finally place that `char` at the end of a `string`. As of now it simply returns the input with spaces subtracted, which is half way there haha.
Interestingly, replacing

```
msg.replace(msg.charAt(i), btc);   // from the bottom
```

with

```
msg += btc;
```

initiates an infinite loop. Any advice would be tremendously appreciated!

```
    String msg = "";
    int key;
    int cnum;
    for(int i = 0; i< message.length();i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(message.charAt(i))){
            msg += (message.charAt(i));
        }
    }



    for(int i = 0; i< msg.length(); i++){  

        char ch = msg.charAt(i);
        key = getKey();

            cnum = (int)ch + key;
            if(cnum > 26){
                cnum -= 26;
            }

        char btc = (char)cnum;
        msg.replace(msg.charAt(i), btc);
    }

return msg;
```

Comment: `String` is immutable, `msg.replace` returns a new `String`, and doesn't modify the original one .

Comment: since both that method and msg += rely on the for statement to avoid infinite repetition, why might using the latter method cause an infinite loop?

Comment: You add one char to msg, then you increment i. So i will never reach msg.length().

Answer (score 1):

Replace `msg.replace(msg.charAt(i), btc);`
with `msg = msg.replace(msg.charAt(i), btc);`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at line

**msg.replace(msg.charAt(i), btc);**

As String is immutable, String.replace() will return a new string and not modify the existing String.

I would suggest you use a StringBuilder(), append the replaced character or append the existing char.